# Log-concave functions whose sums are still log-concave: possible to find a subset?

Tags: calculus, functions, logarithms, convex-analysis

### Rationale:

I am puzzled by a problem of log-concavity, which arises in population dynamics where the curvature of the logarithm of sums is a quantity of interest.

It is well-known that sums of log-convex functions are log-convex (used in Cohen 1980, ref. below). 
However, not all sums of log-concave functions are also log-concave. This is important to me because many convex functions are log-concave.

My investigation so far suggests that log-concavity of the sum is *frequent* when the functions are log-concave but convex, and similar.

> I would therefore like to delineate the set of real-valued log-concave AND convex functions whose sums are log-concave, conditional on some further restrictions.

Any hint appreciated.

### Formal definition of the problem:

Let $r(x) = \ln(b(x)+s(x))$ be the quantity of interest, with $b$ and $s$ functions obeying properties P0-4.

- P0: Defined over some interval $I=[0, x_c] , x_c \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$
- P1: Positive
- P2: Increasing
- P3: Convex
- P4: Log-concave ($\forall x \in I, \ln(f(x))''<0$, $f=b,s$)

> What additional conditions on $b(x)$ and $s(x)$ are needed to obtain $r''(x)<0$?

### Two instructive cases:

1. Let's assume $b(x)=b_m f(x), s(x)=s_m f(x)$, with $f(x)$ obeying P0-4. 
   Then $r(x) = \ln(b_m f(x)+s_m f(x))= \ln(s_m+b_m) + \ln(f(x))$. 
   If $b,s$ obey P0-4, then $\ln(f(x))''<0$ which implies $r''(x)<0$. Here the two functions are nearly equal, but numerical investigations suggest that whenever first and second derivatives of $b(x)$ and $s(x)$ are relatively close, log-concavity follows.
2. Power functions are good examples of convex yet log-concave functions. Let us assume that $s(x)=x^{1+\alpha}$ and $b(x)=x^\beta$, $\alpha,\beta>0$. Using $\alpha = 1$ so that $s(x) = x^2$, one can show numerically that $r(x)$ is concave if $\beta<6$. When $\beta>6$, for some values $x_0 \approx 1$, we observe $r''(x_0)>0$.

### General question:

Q0. Has this problem been treated previously? If yes, for what kind of functions? Polynomials?

### Questions on possible ways to tackle the problem:

Q1. A sufficient condition for log-concavity of the sum ($r''(x)<0$) is log-concavity of $1+b(x)/s(x)$. Could that lead somewhere, studying properties of the ratio $b(x)/s(x)$?

Q2. Flipping the problem on its head, log-convexity of the sum (i.e. $r''(x)>0$) yields a necessary condition $b''(x)s(x)-b'(x)s'(x)>0$ (or equivalent one exchanging $b$ and $s$).

Proof: developing $f''(x)f(x)-f'(x)^2>0$ with $f=b+s$.

Rewriting the above expression suggests $k(x)=b'(x)/s(x)$ has to verify $\ln(k(x))'>0$. 
Is this a worthwhile thread of research, or should I try directly to get sufficient conditions?

Q3. Numerical investigations suggest that two conditions are necessary to meet $\exists x_0 \in I, r''(x_0)>0$:

1. $s(x_0)$ and $b(x_0)$ of commensurate values. Otherwise, the behaviour of one function dominates that of the other, $\ln(b(x)+s(x)) \approx_{x_0} \ln(b(x))$, if $b(x_0)>>s(x_0)$.
2. $s''(x_0)$ and $b''(x_0)$ are very dissimilar (e.g. $6 \times 5 >> 2$ for $x \approx 1$ in the power function example with $\alpha=1$).

Could these be used to derive more general criteria?

Biblio:

> Cohen, J. E. (1980). Convexity properties of products of random nonnegative matrices. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 77(7), 3749-3752.

Comment: Your condition in Q2 is surprising, because it is non symmetric, and it seems false to me. Indeed, for $b=x^2$ and $s=x^7$, you have $b''s-b's'<0$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$. Your condition should be $b''s+s''b-2b's'>0$, which is now symmetric.

Comment: I was probably misunderstanding your parenthesis(or equivalent one exchanging b and s)...

Comment: Yes, I meant that a _necessary_ condition for $r′′(x)>0$ is either $b''s-b's'>0$ or $s''b-b's'>0$. You are of course correct that the more restrictive condition $b′′s+s′′b−2b′s′>0$ works, but I did not find any useful criterion emerging from this relationship.

Comment: Has this problem been solved?

Comment: Not in the general case but see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125287/possible-to-find-a-set-of-log-concave-functions-with-log-concave-sums) for power functions